# Swift dismiss view controller from within container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a container view with a navigation bar which changes buttons and actions dependant upon which view controller is showing.

When the last view controller is shown I need to be able to go back to the previous screen and unwind the segue.

I've tried unwinding the segue and this doesn't work. I've also tried dismissing the view controller and this doesn't work also.

I'm trying to do this outside of the container view via the parent controller where the navigation bar is located.

My controller inside the parent view controller:

```
let processController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProcessController") as! ProcessController
```

I also have the @IBAction:

```
@IBAction func backToCard(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

This is also named inside the storyboard as backToCard

When inside the parent controller I've also tried the following:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToCard", sender: self)
processController.view.removeFromSuperview()
processController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It seems like the processController isn't talking to the view inside the container view.

I could use some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you have a navigation controller embedded in a parent container view and you want to move one step back in the navigation stack?

Comment: Yes. I have a navigation controller inside a container view and I want to move back one step from the parent, not within the container view embedded controller.

Comment: Ok. So I am assuming that your parent controller is apart of a navigation controller. If that is the case, instead of unwind segue why not just call _ = navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) from the parent controller to move back by one? Or is the problem that you cannot access the parent from within child container view (i.e you would like the child to be able to talk to the parent controller)?

Comment: I would like the parent to talk to the child which is inside a container view. The parent navigation controller is a custom one built using a UIView and a bunch of gesture recognisers.

Comment: Do not repeat your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723966/unwind-segue-not-working-from-parent-controller. Edit or delete the earlier question. — The reason you're not getting help is that the question itself remains unclear.

Comment: Or that the community is stumped...